# Constantly display result of php file in another php file

Tags: php

Question is how can I constantly display result of php file in another php file. Basically I have a php file that extracts from DB number of online users and another php file that displays it. The problem is that the "another php file" makes it so that you need to reload the page to see the number of online users updated.

So far using this to display the number:

```
    <div class="side-last-winner">
  <div class="chat-scroll"></div>
<div class="chat-title">
    Reload page to see current number of users
    <div class="chat-o">
      <?php

echo file_get_contents('user_online.php'); php?>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div id="mcaht" class="left-chat"></div>
  <script>
load_messes();
setInterval(load_messes,5000);
</script>
```

Original file with working pages but not counting users:

```
<div class="side-last-winner">
  <div class="chat-scroll"></div>
<!--  <div class="chat-title">
    Test
    <div class="chat-o">
      Online:
      <span class="online-num" id="inf1">0</span>
    </div> 
  </div>-->
  <div id="mcaht" class="left-chat"></div>
  <script>
load_messes();
setInterval(load_messes,5000);
</script>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `setInterval` and `$().load()` function.

```
<div class="side-last-winner">
  <div class="chat-scroll"></div>
<div class="chat-title">
    Reload page to see current number of users
    <div class="chat-o">
      <?php

echo file_get_contents('user_online.php'); php?>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div id="mcaht" class="left-chat"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({
               url :'user_online.php',
               beforeSend: function() 
                   {
                       $('.chat-o').html('Loading...');
                   },
               success: function()
                   {
                       $('.chat-o').load('user_online.php');
                   }
            });
     },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: does that update it all the time and displays it updated all the time without having to reload?

Comment: No it did not solve my answer... I need it to show the number of online users updated all the time without having to reload the page. What you gave me is basically just updating it but need to reload page to see new number

Comment: Okay, but how do I include that in a php file..?

Comment: You just put the code where your `<script>` tag start as in your question.

Comment: so I add setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({
               url :'user_online.php',
         
               success: function()
                   {
                       $('.chat-o').load('user_online.php');
                   }
            });
     },5000);

Comment: Between script tag and load messes

Comment: It works but apparently the other pages I have stopped displaying data from the db.. any idea why?

Comment: Actually wait it happens regardless if it has the auto update feature on.. basically the inclusion in the main index.php file makes all my other pages turn blank as if they cannot read from db..

Comment: Edited description above with original file when my pages were working but didn't display # users online

Comment: I fixed it actually but it takes some times till it shows up. Any idea how I can make the #users online show up instantly?

Comment: made the 5000 after your script be 0 and it is faster now